# Efficient way to get value of parent/adjacent element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On the drop down change, I would like to access the value of selected option's parent element. Is there a better way of React or this will do.

```js
setValue(event) {
    var index = event.target.selectedIndex;
    var optionElement = event.target.parentNode;
    var key = optionElement.getAttribute('data-i');
    var prev = optionElement.getAttribute('data-prev');
}

<li key={index} data-i={index} data-prev={pic.val}>
    <img src={pic.url} height="200" alt="Image preview..." />
    <select onChange={this.setValue} >
        <option selected="selected" value="0">Please Select a Day</option>
        <option value="1" >Monday</option>
        <option value="2" >Tuesday</option>
        <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="4"  >Thursday</option>
        <option value="5" >Friday</option>
        <option value="6" >Saturday</option>
        <option value="7">Sunday</option>
    </select>
</li>)
```

Comment: There's rarely good reasons to try to communicate between components via the DOM. Please read [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) and [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in the docs to learn how to do parent/child communication using props and callbacks.

Comment: @joey - I went through the article. so it is saying every small thing should be a component.  in my case, the image, dropdown should be a different component. I am a  bit confused about how that would solve the problem of communication between component via DOM.